# Date field not showing the pre-filled date coming from Database

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm facing an issue which is probably related to HTML & Thymeleaf. I also attached the screenshots of the scenario.

The input field with the `type="date"` only shows the **dd/mm/yyyy** when I changed the field type to `type="text"` then it shows the date. I want it to show the date regardless of the `type="date"`, so that while editing the record user can see the previous date.

First screenshot is of read mode. And the date of birth field has the `type="text"`.

[image: view record details]

Second screenshot is of edit mode. And you can see that the date is not visible. Input field is of `type="date"` here.

[image: edit record details]

Following is my Thymeleaf template snippet which is relevant for this specific field.

```html
<div class="mb-3">
     <label for="dob" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
     <input type="date" th:field="*{dob}" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob">
</div>
```

Most probably the code anyone need to look at is just this. Rest is all standard code to insert, read etc.

```
public class Student {

    private Optional<LocalDate> dob;

    public Optional<LocalDate> getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Optional<LocalDate> dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

I'd also like to attach the screenshot of the inspect element. You can see that date is coming right, but somehow, datepicker is not showing it. Instead it always show the dd/mm/yyyy.

I want to show the existing date here in the picker so that user can easily see what to change next.

And if we do not set any date here on the edit mode. Regardless, of the value stored in the DB, it will pick the empty date from the UI and update it to DB. So, that's obvious. If it holds the value in the picker then probably it will not behave like this. Any ideas will be great.

**Controller**

```java
@GetMapping("/edit/student/{id}")
public String editStudentDetails(@PathVariable("id") Integer 
    studentId, Model model) {

    Student student = studentService.findStudent(studentId);

    model.addAttribute("student", student);
    model.addAttribute("editMode", true);

    return "editStudent";
}

@PostMapping("/update/student/{id}")
public String editStudentDetails(@PathVariable("id") Integer 
     studentId, Student student, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("student", student);
    model.addAttribute("editMode", true);

    studentService.updateStudent(studentId, student);

    return "redirect:/view/student/"+studentId;
}
```

**RowMapper**

```java
public class StudentRowMapper implements RowMapper<Student> {

    @Override
    public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Student student = new Student();

        student.setId(rs.getInt("student_id"));
        student.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
        student.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));            
        student.setDob(Optional.ofNullable(rs.getDate
        ("date_of_birth")).map(java.sql.Date::toLocalDate));
        student.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
        student.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
        student.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        student.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString("phone_number"));
    
        return student;
    }
```

**Template**

editStudent.html

```html
    <div>
        <form th:action="@{/update/student/{id}(id=${student.id})}"
              th:object="${student}"
              th:method="POST"
              style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="dob" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
                <input type="date" th:field="*{dob}"  th:value="${{student.dob.orElse('')}}" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob">
            </div>   

        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Template**

viewStudent.html

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="dob" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{dob}" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: And with only the screenshot with no code of the controller or object being send we are expected to know what is wrong? We need more information on what is being send, what are the types etc.

Comment: That code shows nothing.  Question - if its all standard, then why do you have a problem ?  Please post enough code for us to replicate teh problem.  Read the help if you are not sure.

Comment: @RohitGupta I hope now you'll get the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute of a date field in html gives and takes a string in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` [[W3 Schools]](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_date_value.asp). So there are many ways of achieving what you want, and one of them could be a case where you convert the date to the relevant string format from the server side and use it to populate the date field in your template.

For example:

In my Controller class, I have some code that converts a Java date object to the string format to send to my template.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model){
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

    // Convert LocalDate to Date Object
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    Date dob = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(zoneId).toInstant());

    // Formatting the date object
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(dob);

    // Should we print this formattedDate, we get a string representation of -> "2023-08-02"

    model.addAttribute("formattedDate", formattedDate);

    return "index";
}
```

Now in my template, I can use that `formmattedDate` object to set the value on the input date field.

```
<form style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="dob" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" th:value="${formattedDate}" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob">
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what is looks like

[image]

So in your scenario, maybe it would be ideal to just have a method in the `Student` class that does the conversion then you can call that method in your template.

```
public class Student{
    ...
    // Method to convert your LocalDate to Date
    @Transient
    public String formattedDOB() {
        // LocalDate localDate = get value of localDate from Optional<LocalDate> dob;

        // Convert LocalDate to Date Object
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        Date dob = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(zoneId).toInstant());

        // Formatting the date object
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(dob);
    
        return formattedDate ;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your template, you can call that method on the student object with `th:value="*{formattedDOB}"`:

```
<form th:action="@{/update/student/{id}(id=${student.id})}"
      th:object="${student}"
      th:method="POST"
      style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="dob" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" th:field="*{dob}" th:value="*{formattedDOB}" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob">
    </div>
</form>
```